# Inheritance and REST API Controllers - Dealing with Subclasses

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following class hierarchy for Coupon and Deals platform am developing::

```
Promotion - abstract
 - Coupon
 - Sale
 - Deal
```

(**Coupon**, **Sale** and **Deal** inherit from Promotion. Promotion has a string attribute called `type` and an abstract method that initializes the the type attributes of the subclasses to a string value. For instance the `type` in coupon gets the value **"Coupon"** etc...)

For each subclass, I have a *DAO* and  *Service* classes like `CouponDAO`, `CouponService`, etc.

In the front-end users can create **Coupon** or **Sale** or a **Deal** through **Angular 2** interface so I decided to have the following controllers:

```
PromotionController - abstract
 - CouponController
 - SaleController
 - DealController
```

(**CouponController**, **SaleController**, **DealController** inherit from **PromotionController** )

The `PromotionController` will contain all the common CRUD functions common to all subclasses and in the specific controllers I will handle specific operations meant for those classes.

A) The issue am facing now is how to instantiate the correct object coming from the client side. For instance when a user submit a **Coupon** or a **Sale** or a **Deal** how do I instantiate the right object. For instance in the **PromotionController** I have a function like this::

```
@RequestMapping(value=CREATE_PROMO, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Promotion promotion){
        promotionService.save(promotion);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
```

**Promotion** which is abstract is the argument of the function. Should I use the factory pattern and the `**type**` attribute to create the right object?
For instance if the **type="Coupon"** then I create Coupon object, if it is **"Sale"** then I create the Sale object

B) Since the controller uses the Services objects it means that I have to declare all the three services objects in the **PromotionController**. Because after instantiating the right object, I need to call its corresponding service to do the job. In the method above I have promotionService which I think should be replaced with the right service of subclass

C) I am looking for how to handle REST APIs that deals with subclasses in the real world like the situation I have described above

D) I was thinking of making it easy for myself  by copying all the CRUD operations to their specific controllers but it seems that will be repetitive code.

I think there is a better way that can be done.

I have also tried if I can find an open source project that deals with this situations but it seems all the projects I found use one class and not inheritance. Their REST/APIs don't handle inheritance situations

Comment: Firstly, I don't recommend you an abstract `@Controller` you inherit from because a `@Controller` is an entry to an application through an endpoint. This may cause some troubles if one endpoint would call 2 or more controllers.

Answer (score 4):

In my view, keep your endpoints simple. From a REST API standpoint, create individual or only one controller and use the following patterns after the controller layer. From what I have seen, it is always better to keep REST endpoints away from inheritance/reuse and apply it later after receiving and validating the requests.

To instantiate service/helper layer from controllers, use factory method pattern:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Create a PromotionServiceFactory which returns the PromotionService implementation depending upon the promotion type.

In controller, invoke corresponding method of promotion service using the factory. The factories still accept arguments of type Promotion.

```
@RequestMapping(value=CREATE_COUPON, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody Promotion promotion){
//helper if adding one more helper layer. The factory invocation is then //transferred to the helper layer
  PromotionService couponService = promotionServiceFactory.get(PROMOTYPES.COUPON);
couponService.save(promotion);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
```

From your questions, it seems like that there are common CRUD/other methods for different promotion types. This is a good candidate of the template pattern in the service layer if some of the steps/sub-tasks are same for every promotion and the others vary. Otherwise, you could just store the common CRUD methods by creating an abstract promotion service.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Create an abstract promotion service with the primary method and implementations of common CRUD methods. Create individual implementations of other promotion service types with respective varying methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this in two ways depending upon the logic.
If you want to keep everything Separate then create a difference endpoints for coupon/deal/sale. That way every endpoint will call its controller and so on.

2) If you think code is same that you can use abstract factory pattern to instantiate the correct service and DAO object.

It all depends on your business requirement, I would prefer the second way if code logic is almost same. One controller per inheritance, so that in future if hierarchy increases you do not need to create multiple classes until required.

Answer (score 0):

to answer you (A), I think you could use requestObject.instanceOf() method, to tell the correct subclass type, then handle with correct handler.