# Java REST Service returns 400

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

Basically I want to do  a POST request with the following body:

```
public class Input extends BaseInput {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String example;

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

```
public class BaseInput implements Serializable {
    private SomeBaseElement sbe;

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

```
public class SomeBaseElement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String baseString;

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

Basically I know that `SomeBaseElement` is the problem, because if I remove it from `BaseInput` the request is successful.
But with it I am getting a `400 BAD REQUEST` error.

Why could that be?

Comment: @leventcinel accepting is default jaxrs @POST annotated method and send is pretty split up, but all in all using jaxrs invocation builder: `builder.accept(APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(data), responseType)`

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your codes, here is the thing. Probably you are accepting at your REST service `BaseInput` object but you are posting an `Input` object, which is a `400-Bad Request`. You can use following method for accepting `Input` object.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/test")
public Response test(Input input) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

If you instead want to accept `BaseInput` at your REST end, you can use factory pattern. I recommend you to checkout following:
[Inheritance and REST API Controllers - Dealing with Subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688285/inheritance-and-rest-api-controllers-dealing-with-subclasses)